# MAMP virtual hosts keep sending me to 'Index of /'

Tags: laravel, mamp, virtual, vhosts, hosts

I'm using Mac so I'm working with MAMP.

In /MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.config I did uncomment the second line:

```
#Virtual hosts  
Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Then in /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf I made this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/User/xxxxx/Sites/mysite"
ServerName mysite
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel-blog/public"
ServerName laravel-blog.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

And my etc/hosts looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost            
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

127.0.0.1       mysite
127.0.0.1       laravel-blog.dev
```

so when I go to mysite:8888/ this redirects me to a page called
'Index of /' with all the folders that I have in htdocs

but when I go to laravel-blog.dev:8888/ it says the page failed to open

so I changed it: instead of laravel-blog.dev , I just used laravel-blog, changed it also in my /etc/hosts and in httpd-vhosts.conf file

and now when I go to laravel-blog:8888/ it redirects me back to this "Index of /" page, even tho the DocumentRoot is set to /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel-blog/public

I have searched for hours and tried a lot of things but still nothing seems to redirect me to the '/public' page of an application, only redirects me back to the 'Index' which is the htdocs.

Anyone an explanation for this? how i can get to '/public'?
And why laravel-blog.dev is not accepted but laravel-blog is?
what has that .dev to do with anything?

Comment: *I'm using Mac so I'm working with MAMP.* use [Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/valet). And forget about **.dev** use **.test**.

Answer (score 0):

All of this is a bit above me, but I find when I am redirecting using MAMP (not sure about MAMP PRO) I have to call the file **index.(extension)** or it will show the index of the whole folder. When you call the file **index.(extension)**, it will open that file.

Hope this helps,

Nat

Comment: I'm sorry.  Something seems wrong with your answer.  Does calling "index.(extension)" show the index of the whole folder or open the file?  Please explain this to me, if I'm mistaken.

Comment: I don't want it to redirect me to my index page(the page that now loads is a simple white page with the title 'Index of /' and then under that are all my app folders from 'htdocs' one under another)

I am working with Laravel, in the folder structure it also has a '/public' folder, which is the one I want to redirect to from my virtual hosts

but no matter what I write, it just sends me to that page with all of my 'htdocs' folders...

Comment: So I always have to manually click on my app folder called "laravel-blog", and once it's open, I have to click on "/public", and only then I get to see my app in the browser...

Comment: Where should I call the file index.extension? I don't get it.. sorry